# "/bin/bash" subprocess.check_output not able to throw exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, exception, process

Using subprocess.check_output with default executable gives me `CalledProcessError` exception if the command throws an exception.
But in the case of `executable="/bin/bash"` it's not throwing `CalledProcessError` exception even though the command throws an exception.

Sometimes this test.py  file throws an exception and because of that got `CalledProcessError` (expected behavior).

```
command = "python3 test.py |& tee test_output.txt"

out = str(
        subprocess.check_output(
          command,
          executable="/bin/bash",
          shell=True,
          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        )
      )
```

Please let me know how to get `CalledProcessError` exception in the case of "/bin/bash" executable.

Comment: I think that indicates that `/bin/bash` isn't returning a non-zero return code.

Comment: yes, then how can we get to know that commands throw an exception or not. nothing present on docs.

Comment: Since you have not indicated what is in `command` in your question, it's hard for anyone to say. It might be possible to write a shell script that does what's needed.

Comment: done, added the `command` as well. Thanks for guiding!

Comment: I think the problem may have something to do with the piping and/or use of `&` in the command. Try removing them and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer after 2-3 days of hustling and posting it now so that it can help others.
Because of the pipe in the command, I am not getting the exception raised by
python script `test.py`

The command should be:
`command = "set -o pipefail; python3 test.py |& tee test_output.txt"`